# Rails nesting convention in regard to views, controller, and models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, convention

So I have two models, with Post resources nested inside of Topic. My question is: am I supposed to nest the Post views into a topic folder? Is it convention to nest the Post controller into a topic folder? How about the model?

I think it'll work whether it's in a topic folder or not, but I just want to know best practices.

Answer (score 0):

In short, don't nest resources in your file system because they are nested logically in your data model.

Three reasons I can think of off the top of my head.

- If your data model is deeply nested, the nested folders would deepen quickly and there may be just one source file per level.
- Rails does not automatically search subfolders of app/models or app/controllers for source files by default, so nesting just adds additional effort on your part (a clue you are not following convention). (However, if using a namespace, it does look in the folder corresponding to the namespace by convention.)
- Data models and hierarchies are complex and change over time; most simply cannot be mapped to a file tree hierarchy. In your example, how would one deal with the scenario where Posts can be nested within both a Topic and let's say, a Profile?

For the most part, using subfolders of app/models and app/controllers is primarily used when putting classes in namespaces. I have seen other uses, but I think they boil down to organizing large numbers of classes.